# How to prove the inequality $abc(a+b+c)^2≤(a^3+b^3+c^3)(ab+bc+ca)$?

Tags: equation-solving

I need to prove something like that:

For a,b,c>0 prove:
$abc(a+b+c)^2≤(a^3+b^3+c^3)(ab+bc+ca)$.

I know that $3abc≤(a^3+b^3+c^3)$, but then I derived $3(ab+bc+ca) ≤ (a+b+c)^2$, I can't move on.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add the Mathematica code you've tried to your question.

Answer (score 4):

For a proof, in the mathematical sense, ask on math.SE.  For a Mathematica verification, here's a way:

```
(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0) \[Implies] 
  Reduce[a*b*c*(a + b + c)^2 <= (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)*(a*b + b*c + c*a),
   {a, b, c}, PositiveReals] // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This is not true on the reals as

```
NMinimize[-a*b*c *(a + b + c)^2 + (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)* (a*b + b*c + c*a), {a, b, c}]
```

says. The inequality is valid on the positive reals:

```
Minimize[-a*b*c*(a + b + c)^2 + (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)*(a*b + b*c + c*a), {a, b, c}, PositiveReals]
(*{0, {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}}*)
```

Addition. Here is the proof by logic tools without bells and jingles

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c},a*b*c*(a + b + c)^2 <= (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)*(a*b + b*c + 
c*a)], PositiveReals]
(*True*)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add conditions that a,b,c>0. I want to prove it on the positive reals

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to disprove by finding a counter-example:

```
FindInstance[a*b*c*(a + b + c)^2 > (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)*(a*b + b*c + c*a), {a, b, c}]

(*    {{a -> -1, b -> -1, c -> 0}}    *)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add conditions that a,b,c>0

Answer (score 1):

We can prove the result directly.

```
Expand[(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)*(a*b + b*c + c*a) - 
   a*b*c*(a + b + c)^2] // Factor
```

> `(a + b) (a + c) (b + c) (a^2 - a b + b^2 - a c - b c + c^2)`

and
$$a^2 - a b + b^2 - a c - b c + c^2=((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2)/2\geq 0$$

```
ForAll[{a, b, c}, a^2 - a b + b^2 - a c - b c + c^2 >= 0] // Resolve
```

> `True`

So if $a,b,c\geq 0$,the inequality is true.

If we depend all of this by MMA, it also work.

```
ForAll[{a, b, c}, 
  a >= 0 && b >= 0 && 
   c >= 0 , (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)*(a*b + b*c + c*a) - 
    a*b*c*(a + b + c)^2 >= 0] // Resolve
```

> `True`

Comment: Maybe your last step can be made with Mathematica too, using for instance this approach https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26283/writing-an-expression-as-sum-of-squares-of-expressions?rq=1

Comment: @yarchik Thanks for your links.

Answer (score 0):

Or similar to the version of @MichaelE2

```
Reduce[a*b*c*(a + b + c)^2 <= (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)*(a*b + b*c + c*a), {a,
b, c}, Reals] // 
Simplify[#, a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0] &

(*   True   *)
```